# Join tables and get the same column to more columns based on the value

Tags: mysql, join

Lets say I join two tables and get a result like

```
id   vendor vendor_id quantity 
1    Sony          1       25 
1    Apple         2       12  
1    HTC           3        5
```

And I want the result to be like

```
id Quantity_Sony Quantity_Apple Quantity_HTC
1             25             12            5
```

How can I do that, I use Left joins to join the tables.  I use mySql

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  ID,
        MAX(CASE WHEN vendor = 'Sony' THEN Quantity END) Quantity_Sony,
        MAX(CASE WHEN vendor = 'Apple' THEN Quantity END) Quantity_Apple,
        MAX(CASE WHEN vendor = 'HTC' THEN Quantity END) Quantity_ATC
FROM
        (
         -- add your existing query here
        ) x
GROUP   BY ID
```